# Pivot/Transpose telephone numbers stored in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have seen a lot of posts and topics regarding pivots and transposing data, I'm either not understanding them (likely) or I'm trying to over complicate what I need to do.

I'm running a simple select statement like so:

```
SELECT Customer, Telephone
FROM DetailsTable
WHERE Customer = 74270571
GROUP BY Customer, Telephone
```

This returns:

```
Customer | Telephone
74270571 | 01556589962
74270571 | 07756563729
```

And what I am trying to get is

```
Customer | Tel1         | Tel2
74270571 | 01556589962  | 07756563729
```

There can be a max of 5 tel numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple `Telephone` values for each `Customer`, the easiest way to get the result would be to use a windowing function like `row_number` to create a unique value for each `Telephone`/`Customer` combination. Once you have this value, then you can `PIVOT` the result using an aggregate function and CASE expression or the PIVOT function.

Having up to five telephone numbers, makes this easy to write the query as a hard-coded or static version.  Using an aggregate function with a CASE expression the code would be:

```
select 
  customer,
  Tel1 = max(case when rn = 1 then telephone else null end),
  Tel2 = max(case when rn = 2 then telephone else null end),
  Tel3 = max(case when rn = 3 then telephone else null end),
  Tel4 = max(case when rn = 4 then telephone else null end),
  Tel5 = max(case when rn = 5 then telephone else null end)
from
(
  select customer, telephone,
   rn = row_number() over(partition by customer order by telephone)
  from DetailsTable
) x
group by customer;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd298/1/0)

If you want to use the PIVOT function, then the code would be:

```
select customer,
  Tel1,
  Tel2,
  Tel3, 
  Tel4, 
  Tel4
from
(
  select customer, telephone,
   col = 'Tel'+cast(row_number() over(partition by customer order by telephone)
                    as varchar(1))
  from DetailsTable
) x
pivot
(
  max(telephone)
  for col in (Tel1, Tel2, Tel3, Tel4, Tel5)
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd298/2). Both give a result:

```
| CUSTOMER |       TEL1 |       TEL2 |   TEL3 |   TEL4 |
|----------|------------|------------|--------|--------|
| 74270571 | 1556589962 | 7756563729 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: I honestly love this place some days. The answer was perfect, Thank you so much.